# How to tell if my hosting data is valid or a fake copy

Tags: ip, dns-domain, web-hosting, shared-hosting

I'm investigating an issue where we have consistent performance issues with our company web host and bad statistcs data in our hosting console. Our hosting provider console says our IP address is one thing, but if you `dig` our domain or do a `traceroute`, it shows a different domain. We have no special DNS settings with the host.

In addition to that, the data usage reported by our analytics show much higher volume (more than 130 times) than what our hosting dashboard is reporting. The monthly volume our hosting dashboard shows for our site isn't even close to what our daily volume is.

Everything in the dashboard says its our stuff/domain but IPs and bandwidth don't match up.The site files the server shows looks right. But our performance is suggestive of shared-hosting and the host provider says the hosting is not shared.

We use SSl but its managed through the hosting provider. Doing a check on the SSl shows the IP I see in `traceroute` and its in front of nginx but we don't manage an nginx configuration and have no access to host OS console.

I'm just trying to see what I can do to confirm if our hosting is valid. Is there a way to confirm my hosting information is valid?

Comment: What type of analytics are you using?

Comment: Google analytics. Update from hosting provider says usage stats don't work in their interface and gave no ETA on a fix for that (wtf?), but they are working to fix the issue with wrong IP showing in admin interface. Migrating from this host is a big job but we may have to do it if they can't fix the performance issues and admin data issues.

Comment: Google Analytics is client side - it doesn't take some things into account. For example, if you have a CDN, your hosting provider will see massively less traffic than GA - Google counts all the data coming from the CDN, while the hosting provider only sees requests which aren't served from the CDN, giving a much smaller number.

Comment: The way we calculated the expected number is based on size of assets served only from host per initial page load...around 50KB (so excluding all jquery, images and other cdn files) per unique user so our number is on the conservative end. That number, times our average number of unique users per month is still 130 times higher than what the hosting provider shows we use per month. Again -the hosting provider has already stated their stats are not working.

Comment: In that case, I suspect something isn't right on the host end. It could be transparently caching (e.g. all requests from your site are actually cached by the hosting provider) but that would normally be called out as a feature if used!